# Questions Regarding Sampling Bias

Tags: sampling, biostatistics, research-design, selection-bias

I'm taking a course in R: "Data Analysis in R" on Coursera, and I came across this question during the lecture:

A retail store considering updates to their credit card policies randomly samples 1000 of their credit card holders to survey on the phone. The phone calls are made during business hours, therefore there is a lower rate of responses from members who work during these hours. What type of bias is this indicative of?

Is there a reason why "convenience sample" bias would not be the right answer? The other answer choices were voluntary response, non-response, or none of the above.

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Convenience sampling has more to do with how you select your sample, for example, if you had different means of contacting people but you chose to contact them by phone because it was easier for you - the researcher, then this would be convenience sampling.

However, if you were going to use the phone anyway (let's assume this is the most reasonable approach) then there is no convenience, since you are not selecting a specific subset of people (for example people who work on the phone and so are easier to get a hold of).

This looks more like a non-response bias since only certain types of people will answer the phone during these hours. If you are calling their home number (is that still a thing?) then (mostly) people who are at home will answer, i.e. the *unemployed*.

Voluntary response happens when people voluntarily select themselves, let's say you put an ad somewhere about your product with a phone number and you get a certain type of people calling you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @user2974951!

Comment: @JackJackAttack0214 https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers